# Does angle trisection imply cube root construction and vice versa?

Tags: real-numbers, geometric-construction

Im curious to know what constructions become possible with the inclusion of angle trisection.  Including the construction of heptagons and other polygons, and by how much do the constructible numbers extend within the algebraics?

Comment: It's useful to phrase this in terms of field extensions. A real $r$ is *trisection-constructible* iff there is a tower of fields $$\mathbb{Q}=K_0\subseteq K_1\subseteq ...\subseteq K_n\ni r$$ such that for each $i$ either $[K_{i+1}:K_i]\le 2$ or $K_{i+1}=K_i(\tan({\arctan(\alpha)\over 3}))$ for some $\alpha\in K_i$. Similarly, a real $r$ is *cube-doubling-constructible*  iff there is a tower of fields $$\mathbb{Q}=K_0\subseteq K_1\subseteq ...\subseteq K_n\ni r$$ such that for each $i$ either $[K_{i+1}:K_i]\le 2$ or $K_{i+1}=K_i(\sqrt[3]{\alpha})$ for some $\alpha\in K_i$.

Comment: (This parallels the [field-tower-definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number#Transformation_into_algebra) of the constructible numbers themselves.) That doesn't answer the question of course, but it turns it into a purely algebraic one.  Note that thinking along these lines we can show that no finite set of additional construction methods will ever get you all the algebraic numbers: consider an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ whose degree is some prime not dividing any of the degrees of the extensions corresponding to those finitely many new methods.